# How can I create an array of numbers based on which checkboxes are checked in a form?

Tags: forms, checkbox, cakephp-3.0

I need to allow multiple values to be selected, and I want to create an array of the selected values. Here is what I have so far:

```
<p>Select Multiple Values
    <?php echo $this->Form->create(); ?>
    <?php foreach($possibilities as $possibility):
     echo $this->Form->input($possibility['name'], 
         ['type' => 'checkbox', 'value' => $possibility['id']]);
    endforeach; ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->button(__('Submit'));
    echo $this->Form->end(); ?></p>
```

How can I check this form to see what values have been selected and store them in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this script:

```
echo $this->Form->select('possibilities', $possibilities, [
    'multiple' => 'checkbox'
]);
```

In controller simply:

```
$selected = $this->request->data('possibilities');
```

You can visit this [CookBook Page](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-select-pickers)